# Showing $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ = $g(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$ and $g$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have an open ball $E^n$ of center $(a_1, a_2, a_3,...,a_n)$ and radius $r$.

$f$ is a differentiable real-valued function on that open ball. 
$f_{x_n}$=$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} = 0$ .

I do not understand how there is a unique real-valued function $g$ on the open ball in $E^{n-1}$ of center $(a_1,...,a_{n-1})$ and radius $r$ such that $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ = $g(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$, and this $g$ is differentiable.

Any help with showing this would be great thank you.

Comment: Think about what $\partial_{x_n} f = 0 $ means. Keeping the other $x_i$ constant, I can change $x_n$ without affecting the value of $f$. This suggests that $f$ is independent of $x_n$ entirely, that is, instead of computing $f(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, x_n)$, you could always compute $f(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, a_n)$ and get the same result. Can you now think of an appropriate $g$?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 hmmm I am not seeing immediately seeing a g that works

Comment: Assuming you understood the rest of the spiel above, try $$ g(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}) = f(x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}, a_n)$$

Comment: can you explain a little more I am still confused with what you had provided me with

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean-value theorem to show that $f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_n) = f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},a_n)$ for each $(x_1,...,x_n)$. This means we can just define $g(x_1,...,x_{n-1}) = f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},a_n)$ to get the desired function. (Recall $a_n$ is constant here so this is just a function of the first $n-1$ variables).

Comment: I spent some time looking at the mean-value theorem and don't see how it is explicitly applicable to get the $a_n$ term

Comment: Ok I see how you get $f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},a_n)$ for each $(x_1,...,x_n)$, but how is $g$ differentiable?